# how to properly generate String list for a .bat file?

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to make a list of strings like this:
{https://pastebin.com/5azvnN8L}
with the part labeled num1 , num2 , exedra, going all the way to 100
but I found this to be a difficult task copy and pasting and editing the num area .
So I was wondering if there was a way to do this automatically with a command in cmd or an application accessible to windows10

sorry for the pastebin link i had trouble with the code embedding thing on stack overflow posting

Comment: you mean each line will have `num` and the url? Will the url be same on each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for /L` loop to iterate over a range of numbers to dynamically build your variables, but you'll need to enable delayed expansion first so that you get a different random number each time.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%A in (1,1,100) do set /a num%%A=!RANDOM!%%%dig%+1
```

or if you want the actual `set` commands themselves to be in a new file, you don't need delayed expansion and can just do

```
for /L %%A in (1,1,100) do >>file.txt echo set /a num%%A=%%RANDOM%% %%%% %%dig%%+1
```

You need to double up the `%`s to escape them.

Comment: @swapclick please read, [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)